# Is it bad practice to provide a SOAP service without WSDL?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I'm using PHP's [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) to access a SOAP service. The provider of the service has told me that their WSDL is only for development and I shouldn't use it in production.

The [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) constructor expects the first argument to be the WSDL of the service, but also allows null, when working in non-WSDL mode.

I've been searching the RFCs and W3C for guidance, but haven't been able to find anything definitive on the use of WDSLs with SOAP.

Should someone who provides a SOAP service also provide a WSDL?

If someone who provides a SOAP service with a WSDL, is it correct to query that WSDL for each SOAP call?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it bad practice to provide a SOAP service without WSDL?

I wouldn't call it bad practice. It is a convention to provide a WSDL file at `?wsdl` but you are not required to. There might be a reason why the provider doesn't want to expose the WSDL file, e.g. if it's a private web service.

> The provider of the service has told me that their WSDL is only for development and I shouldn't use it in production.

So there is a WSDL file but it shouldn't be used? Now that sounds like a bad practice to me. IMO there should either be a valid WSDL file or no file at all. A file that doesn't reflect the actual web service will just cause confusion.

> is it correct to query that WSDL for each SOAP call?

Yes the WSDL file is cached anyways and hence won't be queried every time.

Comment: Can you give me a link to any official documentation/RFC which says its OK/reasonable to request the the WSDL for each instantiation of a PHP SoapClient object

Comment: @Dom I don't think that there is any documentation which explicitly states that. And as I said: You are not requesting the WSDL with every instantiation. It will only be requested when its time to live has expired.

Comment: @Dom you won't find documentation for everything in real life :)  You just know that it is cached so its ok to use it as much as you need.

Comment: @simon I was being given the run around by the service provider (saying that the WSDL was only for development and I should't be requesting it at all in production) and I wanted to point to to an RFC or documentation on the W3C so I could tell them their service was not in line with standards and that the fix should be at their end, not the work around of their poor code at my end.